# Multiple levels of subclasses and method chaining

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, subclass, chaining

I am working on the following structure:

- `Buffer`
- `XBuffer` extends `Buffer`
- `XYBuffer` extends `XBuffer`

All objects should be instantiable, so no `abstract`, in order to support forward compatability.

I have came up with the following, with pitfalls/issues I will describe below:

```
public class Buffer<S extends Buffer<S>> {
    protected final int bufferType;
    protected final int bufferDataType;

    protected int bufferId;
    protected boolean created;

    public Buffer(final int bufferType, final int bufferDataType) {
        this.bufferType = bufferType;
        this.bufferDataType = bufferDataType;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public S create() {
        assertNotCreated();
        bufferId = GL15.glGenBuffers();

        created = true;
        return (S)this;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public S bind() {
        assertCreated();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(bufferType, bufferId);

        return (S)this;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public S fillData(final float[] data) {
        assertCreated();

        FloatBuffer dataBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(data.length).put(data);
        dataBuffer.flip();
        GL15.glBufferData(bufferType, dataBuffer, bufferDataType);

        return (S)this;
    }

    public void delete() {
        assertCreated();

        GL15.glDeleteBuffers(bufferId);
    }

    public int getBufferId() {
        return bufferId;
    }

    public boolean hasBeenCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    private void assertCreated() {
        if (!hasBeenCreated()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Buffer has not been created.");
        }
    }

    private void assertNotCreated() {
        if (hasBeenCreated()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Buffer has been created already.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Buffer(" + bufferType + ", " + bufferDataType + ", " + bufferId + ", " + created + ")";
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ArrayBuffer<S extends ArrayBuffer<S>> extends Buffer<S> {
    public ArrayBuffer(final int bufferDataType) {
        super(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferDataType);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class StaticDrawArrayBuffer extends ArrayBuffer<StaticDrawArrayBuffer> {
    public StaticDrawArrayBuffer() {
        super(GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }
}
```

Now the following happens:

- Instantiating any of the lowest level subclasses works fine, `StaticDrawArrayBuffer` works as expected.
- `ArrayBuffer` does not work as expected, as I cannot instantiate it anymore without using generics. (*Keep in mind: The generics used here are only there to help me, not to actually provide generic functionality*)
- `Buffer` does not work as expected either with the same issue as `ArrayBuffer`.

What do I want?

- Everything I have now, except that I can instantiate `Buffer` and `ArrayBuffer` without using generics.

How would I do this?

To clarify more, these statements should all compile:

- `Buffer buffer = new Buffer().create().bind();`
- `ArrayBuffer arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer().create.bind();`
- `StaticDrawArrayBuffer staticDrawArrayBuffer = new StaticDrawArrayBuffer().create.bind()`

If I would not use any generics at all, then `new ArayBuffer().create()` will return a `Buffer`, resulting in that it cannot be assigned to `ArrayBuffer` anymore. It does leave chaining of `Buffer` methods intact, but it would furthermore also break if the chain would contain methods only available to `ArrayBuffer`.

If it helps, I have the ability to use Java 8 if it is a almost bugfree (it should be now, I think?), considering this project won't see real daylight for a long while anyway.

Comment: Are you asking how you can use the type you made generic without generics? Don't *make it* generic. Given Java type erasure, what do you mean by "*generic functionality*"?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I cannot make it not generic, then the functionality breaks as described in my newest edit. The best 'easy' solution I can do is have a non-generic `RawArrayBuffer` and `RawBuffer` type. With *generic functionality* I mean something like `List<String>`, where the `String` type parameter is also actually used in the resulting object.

Comment: Please read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) and explain what you're asking. Also, Java 8 is scheduled for release in March... I wouldn't take it to production until there have been a few sub-releases myself, but someone has to be the guinea pig.

Comment: Just brainstorming: Make a generic supertype, then create a subclass which derives from MySupertype<Object>, thus resolving the generic and hiding it from the user?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I understand that the code does compile and not produce runtime errors, **however** it leaves nasty *found raw type* messages in all modern IDE's, which is actually not an issue in my case, but the warnings are still there.

Comment: Is there an option to annotate that a type argument is not required, or hide a type argument to the outside world altogether? I have never seen it myself, so I am kind of doubting it.

Comment: You can always use the `capture-of` type, which sgiykd get rid of the warning and raw type messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about Covariant return types instead of generics?

```
public class ArrayBuffer extends Buffer {
    public ArrayBuffer(final int bufferDataType) {
        super(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferDataType);
    }

    public ArrayBuffer create() {
        super.create();
        return this;
    }
    public ArrayBuffer bind() {
        super.bind();
        return this;
    }
}

public class StaticDrawArrayBuffer  extends ArrayBuffer {
    public StaticDrawArrayBuffer() {
        super(GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }


    public StaticDrawArrayBuffer bind() {
        super.bind();
        return this;
    }
}
```

AFAIK this should compile now:

```
Buffer buffer = new Buffer().create().bind();
ArrayBuffer arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer().create().bind();
StaticDrawArrayBuffer staticDrawArrayBuffer = new StaticDrawArrayBuffer().create().bind()
```

Comment: It leads to code duplication sadly. It is true that your answer is a valid one, but I'm not really happy with introducing this to all classes.

Comment: It's too bad Java doesn't have a `covariant_return` specifier for methods that indicates that calls of a method in subclasses will be of the subclass type (with the restriction that methods declared as `covariant_return` would have to return an object of the class's type, possibly even just `this`). Behind the scenes, the compiler could perhaps replicate the method into all of the subclasses with the right type to avoid bytecode incompatibilities, or if references to private members of the parent class are used do similarly to what you have and call the parent method and cast the return value.

Comment: Í'll just go with this then, it's essentially still copy paste + search and replace to make all subclasses, so apart from one time it's not more work in all reality.

Comment: Interestingly the compiler is smart enough to figure out that I am overriding `Buffer`s `create()` in `ArrayBuffer`, instead of letting both versions of `create()` live next to eachother.

Comment: The compiler got that smart only since Java 1.5. See https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/covariant_return_types_in_java.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to separate the part of your code that does not use generics from the generic inheritance tree (which is kind of clunky to begin with, in my opinion, but that's mainly an issue with the way Java was designed and the design choices made when generics were added to the language).

What I mean by that is to do the following:

```
public class Buffer extends BaseBuffer<Buffer> {
    public Buffer(final int bufferType, final int bufferDataType) {
        super(bufferType, bufferDataType);
    }    
}

public class ArrayBuffer extends BaseArrayBuffer<ArrayBuffer> {
    public ArrayBuffer(final int bufferDataType) {
        super(bufferDataType);
    }
}
```

Where `BaseBuffer` and `BaseArrayBuffer` are the classes you call `Buffer` and `ArrayBuffer`.

(Though it seems you may already be doing this, based on one of your comments?)

The issue with this method is that you could not pass a `StaticDrawArrayBuffer` as an `ArrayBuffer` or an `ArrayBuffer` as a `Buffer` (or store them in variables of those types) as they are no longer subclasses of those specific types. You'd have to use something like `BaseArrayBuffer<StaticDrawArrayBuffer>` and `BaseBuffer<ArrayBuffer>` for that instead.

Comment: This leads to a lot of extra complexity aswell... It might be that `RawBuffer extends Buffer<Buffer>`, and similar for the `ArrayBuffer` would be better? Or does it break subclassing yet again then.

Comment: @skiwi I think that would work pretty much the same way, only you'd need to throw around more `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotations. Java just isn't a good language for the sort of elegance you desire.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest that you rethink your architecture. Instantiating both children and parent classes is a bad, bad idea. Suppose, one day you wish to change parent behaviour (because you use it and requirements have changed), while leaving child intact. What then?

Use Strategies instead. Specify Buffer interface (why do you need it? What it's supposed to do?) and give each instance a Strategy to fulfill their purpose.

Then you'll have only Buffer that contains Buffers and Strategies to implement your logic:

```
public interface BufferingStrategy
{
    public Buffer create() ;
    public Buffer bind();
    public Buffer fillData(final float[] data);
}
```

Comment: The parent and child behaviour are interleaved forever, this cannot change. This is built directly on top of OpenGL/LWJGL to get rid of all the static calls and instead work in an object orientated way. I agree normally interfaces are the best, but in this case it differs.

Comment: Well, in that case I personally don't know why don't you just _cast_ to a suitable generic _after_ the instantiation of a raw type. Generics in Java are fake anyway, so if you want to collect syntax sugar --- just do it. Anyway, I stand on my own: to instantiate grandparent, parent and son is a big mistake. There have to be another solution to your problem if this source code is under you control.

Comment: @Undespairable What exactly do you mean "to instantiate grandparent, parent and son is a big mistake"? `ArrayBuffer` does not appear to require a previously-existing `Buffer` to be instantiated, nor does `StaticDrawArrayBuffer` appear to require a previously-existing `ArrayBuffer` to be instantiated.

Comment: I mean just that: topic starter has this kind of class hierarchy: A<-B<-C, and allows (moreover, specifically requests the ability) to instantiate either of these classes, which is potentially dangerous because of later changes. Those three must either have _one_ common ancestor and be just siblings, or be not related at all, sharing only interface, or --- better, in my opinion --- be just one Buffer with three types of aggregated behaviour.